# HTML Table autom. expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

```
http://jsfiddle.net/bzL7p87k/
```

I have Placeholders in this Table, who fill with special words, but what is when I have more then the 4 rows? When I have 21 Placeholder for 21 Rows?

---

I mean that so:
I have only one row with the Placeholder, like this: `jsfiddle.net/bzL7p87k/1/`

And in my CMS, I have Placeholder for 30 rows, is there a possibility that the table expands automatically?

Comment: Expands? What do you mean?

Comment: automacially add rows and count for this special given Placeholder

Comment: yes, but how?? i need a special source or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use append in jQuery. It is easy to implement. Check this [blog](http://www.ssiddique.info/different-ways-to-add-row-to-a-table-using-jquery.html) and just do the same.

For your example here is a code. Just know how to use JS. If your table ID now is mytable

```
$('#mytable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>{{TOOL}}</td><td>{{TOOL}}</td><td>{{TOOL}}</td><td>{{TOOL}}</td></tr>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in jQuery. Something like this:

```
$("table tbody").append("<tr><td>Row Content</td></tr>");
```

Comment: how can I use this, specially for my example?

Comment: @user3714925 Where is the JavaScript code in your case?

Comment: it's a part of an big html, special for this table I doesnt have n JS, because I dont know, how I add new rows when more than 8 Placeholders are given.